# Why does Ms. Monet hate Andy Campbell?

Tags: plot-explanation, fist-fight

In fist fight, Andy Campbell is obviously a pushover, and most people don't respect him.

What is curious though, is the explicit hatred of Ms. Monet.

Why would she hate Andy Campbell and be obsessed by him to the point of suggesting using knives instead of fists, when she took the initiative to talk to Strickland?

[image: Fist_Fight_2017___30:28]

Comment: Because he is not her type and she has no interest in Andy's character.. (being a lame, feared guy etc... )